# Keep getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException On Phone not in Emulator

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Heey,

I need some help on a Exception i keep hitting with my app,

The Exception fires in this piece of code

```
Map mapView = new Map() 
        { 
            CredentialsProvider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider("OurKey"),
            Margin = new Thickness(6.0),
            IsEnabled = false,
            Center = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(newEvent.EventLat), Convert.ToDouble(newEvent.EventLon)),
            ZoomLevel = 15
        };
```

Where i get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on the `Center = new GeoCoordinate` piece containing the following info

> The value of the parameter must be from -90.0 to 90.0.
>   Parameter name: Latitude

But the `newEvent.EventLat` is "51.4430624" so completely Valid to me isnt it?

Now the even weirder part is this happens only when i run it on my Nokia Lumia 800 when i fire it up on the emulator it just works fine.

So i really need help on this one i cant find anything on it on the internet.

Comment: Have you tried `double.Parse(newEvent.EventLat)` instead? Just in case... Also, if you pass that value `51.4430624` straight to `GeoCoordinate`'s first parameter, does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the newEvent.EventLat is "51.4430624" so completely Valid to me isnt it?

Unless your decimal separator on the phone is `,`
Regional settings is a typical thing to get wrong between an emulator and the real thing.

Consider

```
//Convert.ToDouble(newEvent.EventLat)
double.Parse(newEvent.EventLat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Wow kinda big facepalm over here that i have to force the right *Culture* to get this working :S but beside that a Huge thanks from me for such a quick and clear answer.